# ReverseGeocode Callback Multiple Call - iOS - Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, reverse-geocoding

I am using the GMGeocoder.ReverseGeocodeCord(position, callback) to retrive an address. I successfully get the address but I keep on receiving multiple calls to this callback method.

I have tried many different ways on implementing the reverse geocode and I get the same problems.

Even trying implementing the CLGeocoder and I get also the same results.

how I invoke the geocoder:

```
Console.WriteLine("BEFOREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder();
geocoder.ReverseGeocodeCord(position, reverseGeocodeCallback);
Console.WriteLine("AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR");
```

Here is the callback method:

```
private void reverseGeocodeCallback(ReverseGeocodeResponse response, NSError error)
        {
            if (error != null || response == null || response.FirstResult == null)
            {
                if (infoWindow != null)
                {
                    infoWindow.LabelAddress.Text = string.Empty;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Error reversing geocode address");
            }
            else
            {
                string result = string.Empty;

                var placemark = response.FirstResult;

                string address = placemark.Thoroughfare;
                string city = placemark.Locality;
                string postalcode = placemark.PostalCode;

                string[] array = { address, city, postalcode };

                Console.WriteLine("Add: " + address + ", " + city + ", " + postalcode);

                bool firstAdded = true;
                foreach (string item in array)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
                    {
                        if (firstAdded)
                        {
                            firstAdded = false;
                            result += item;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result += ", " + item;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (infoWindow != null)
                {
                    infoWindow.LabelAddress.Text = result;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the results I am getting:

```
2017-06-16 17:44:03.485 SatNaviOS[788:555951] Add: 1 Fulbeck Avenue, Worthing, BN13 3FG
2017-06-16 17:44:03.487 SatNaviOS[788:555951] BEFOREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
2017-06-16 17:44:03.488 SatNaviOS[788:555951] AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
2017-06-16 17:44:03.597 SatNaviOS[788:555951] Add: 1 Fulbeck Avenue, Worthing, BN13 3FG
2017-06-16 17:44:03.599 SatNaviOS[788:555951] BEFOREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
2017-06-16 17:44:03.600 SatNaviOS[788:555951] AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
2017-06-16 17:44:03.809 SatNaviOS[788:555951] Add: 1 Fulbeck Avenue, Worthing, BN13 3FG
2017-06-16 17:44:03.810 SatNaviOS[788:555951] BEFOREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
2017-06-16 17:44:03.811 SatNaviOS[788:555951] AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
2017-06-16 17:44:04.083 SatNaviOS[788:555951] Add: 1 Fulbeck Avenue, Worthing, BN13 3FG
2017-06-16 17:44:04.085 SatNaviOS[788:555951] BEFOREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
2017-06-16 17:44:04.086 SatNaviOS[788:555951] AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
2017-06-16 17:44:04.476 SatNaviOS[788:555951] Add: 1 Fulbeck Avenue, Worthing, BN13 3FG
2017-06-16 17:44:04.478 SatNaviOS[788:555951] BEFOREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
2017-06-16 17:44:04.479 SatNaviOS[788:555951] AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
2017-06-16 17:44:04.722 SatNaviOS[788:555951] Add: 1 Fulbeck Avenue, Worthing, BN13 3FG
2017-06-16 17:44:04.724 SatNaviOS[788:555951] BEFOREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
2017-06-16 17:44:04.725 SatNaviOS[788:555951] AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
2017-06-16 17:44:04.896 SatNaviOS[788:555951] Add: 1 Fulbeck Avenue, Worthing, BN13 3FG
2017-06-16 17:44:04.898 SatNaviOS[788:555951] BEFOREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
2017-06-16 17:44:04.899 SatNaviOS[788:555951] AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
2017-06-16 17:44:05.242 SatNaviOS[788:555951] Add: 1 Fulbeck Avenue, Worthing, BN13 3FG
2017-06-16 17:44:05.244 SatNaviOS[788:555951] BEFOREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
2017-06-16 17:44:05.245 SatNaviOS[788:555951] AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
2017-06-16 17:44:05.362 SatNaviOS[788:555951] Add: 1 Fulbeck Avenue, Worthing, BN13 3FG
2017-06-16 17:44:05.364 SatNaviOS[788:555951] BEFOREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
2017-06-16 17:44:05.365 SatNaviOS[788:555951] AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
2017-06-16 17:44:05.587 SatNaviOS[788:555951] Add: 1 Fulbeck Avenue, Worthing, BN13 3FG
2017-06-16 17:44:05.589 SatNaviOS[788:555951] BEFOREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
2017-06-16 17:44:05.590 SatNaviOS[788:555951] AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
2017-06-16 17:44:05.804 SatNaviOS[788:555951] Add: 1 Fulbeck Avenue, Worthing, BN13 3FG
2017-06-16 17:44:05.806 SatNaviOS[788:555951] BEFOREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
2017-06-16 17:44:05.807 SatNaviOS[788:555951] AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
2017-06-16 17:44:05.981 SatNaviOS[788:555951] Add: 1 Fulbeck Avenue, Worthing, BN13 3FG
2017-06-16 17:44:05.983 SatNaviOS[788:555951] BEFOREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
2017-06-16 17:44:05.984 SatNaviOS[788:555951] AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
2017-06-16 17:44:06.198 SatNaviOS[788:555951] Add: 1 Fulbeck Avenue, Worthing, BN13 3FG
```

You can see that the reverseGeocodeCallback is being called multiple times. However, I only invoke it once. Thanks

Comment: the problem must be elsewhere in your code, since it is invoking the "BEFORE" and "AFTER" calls multiple times, and not just the geocoder callback.

Comment: I know, it looks like this, but it is not, the callback is invoking the method is it is being called. If I commend out the geocode then it only prints once before and after. how is this possible?

Comment: You were correct, it was being invoked by ViewWillLayoutSubviews. Somehow, by changing the label it invokes that method. Thanks for leading me to a solution :)